# Changing timezone of alertmanager in kube-prometheus-stack helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager, kube-prometheus-stack

I am currently using emailing alerts for our application. One of the contents of the email is the start and end time of the alert but they are displaying as UTC+0000.

Tried using  .Start.Local.Format but realized that the only time that alertmanager pod has it UTC+0000. Was wondering if there is a way I can set the pod timezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the timezone of pods by using [volumes and volumeMount](https://evalle.github.io/blog/20200914-kubernetes-tz)s  to specify the timezone, like :

```
volumeMounts:
    - name: tz-config
      mountPath: /etc/localtime
  volumes:
    - name: tz-config
      hostPath:
        path: /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago
```

Or you can use the "TZ" environment variable in the container section inside the pod spec, to configure the desired time zone:

```
spec:
 containers:
  - name:
  foo-bar
  image: foobar:latest
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  env:
   - name: TZ
   value: America/Chicago
```

This changes the timezone displayed by the pod, which you can confirm using "kubectl exec POD date".

The Default Dashboards Timezone is utc. Attaching the [list of timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for reference.